# ¿Por qué da null pointer exception en el primer caso y no en el segundo?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código que da error

```
class Nodo {
        int info;
        Nodo sig;
        }
Nodo raiz;

public void insertar(int x) {
        
        Nodo insertado = new Nodo();
        insertado.info = x;
    
        if (raiz == null) {
            raiz = insertado;
            return;
        }
    
        if (insertado.info > raiz.info) {
            insertado.sig = raiz;
            //raiz.ant =  insertado;
            raiz = insertado;
            return;
        }
        
        Nodo reco = raiz;
        Nodo recob = reco.sig;
        
        while (recob.info > insertado.info && recob != null )  {
        reco = reco.sig;
        recob = recob.sig;
                }  //EN ESTE WHILE ESTÁ EL ERROR
```

lo que no entiendo es por qué el siguiente bloque de código si compila bien:

```
public void mostrarElementos() {
            
            Nodo reco ;
            reco = raiz;
        while (reco != null) {      
        System.out.println(reco.info);
        reco = reco.sig;
        }
```

si en ambos casos el while estaría logrando que un puntero (en el primer caso "recob" y en el segundo "reco") termine apuntando a null.

Comment: pero el error es de compilación? Porque en el encabezado hablas de NPE y eso no se ve en compilación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin haber entendido la totalidad del problema, te puedo decir que esto no está bien:

```
recob.info > insertado.info && recob != null
```

Si recob fuera null (cosa que verificas en la *segunda* parte de ese `&&`) entonces tendrías un NPE porque estás tratando de utilizar un miembro de recob antes de saber si recob es null. Esto se debe a que las evaluaciones se hacen de izquierda a derecha. Tendrías que colocar

```
recob != null && recob.info > insertado.info
```

para que evites el NPE.